# How to block/prevent navigation in React Navigation v5?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v5

I need **prevent** navigation if I'm editing a certain screen.

I found this in the documentation: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/5.x/custom-routers/#blocking-navigation-actions but don't have a clear example, even because I'm using `createStackNavigator`

How should I implement to get access to this `getStateForAction`?
Or there is another way to block/prevent users to go to another screen globally?

Here is an example of how I'm doing the navigator.

```js
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
const StackNavigator = createStackNavigator<TTopLevelParams>();

const RootNavigator: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <StackNavigator.Navigator initialRouteName={StartNav}>
      <StackNavigator.Screen
        component={IntroNav}
        name={IntroNav}
      />
      <StackNavigator.Screen
        component={StartNav}
        name={StartNav}
      />
    </StackNavigator.Navigator>
  );
};

export default RootNavigator;
```